# How to expand fields of a SharePoint List Item

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I am encountering an issue when retrieving specific fields/column on a SharePoint list item.

I can get some fields but I cannot specify which columns. Also, if I have more than five custom fields the exceeding custom fields don't show up by default

This works:

`GET /beta/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items?expand=fields`

This doesn't:

`GET /beta/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items?expand=fields(select=Column1,Column2)`

### Update:

*I can now see my other columns being returned. It seems that the default behavior is that it will not return empty columns. I still have not figure out how to specify columns I want to be returned.*

Answer (score 1):

If we want to get the `Title` column of all items in a SharePoint list, we can sent the following request to Graph API endpoint:

`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items?$expand=fields($select=Title)`

Comment: this doesn't work for me, it returns a bunch of other fields as well:  @odata.etag
createdDateTime, eTag, id, lastModifiedDateTime, webUrl, createdBy, lastModifiedBy, parentReference, contentType, fields@odata.context.